# How can I stop Skype from stalling or at least automatically detect the failure and restart it?

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, skype

I have Ubuntu on 3 different computers a Samsung NC10, a Samsung N150 and a desktop computer with a Xeon in it and some NVidia graphics card (don't know the exact specs offhand), they are all exhibiting the same issue with Skype.

Every once in a while Skype will stall in the sense that I can still use the Skype UI, but I won't receive any notifications, if I try to call someone it will say "Conference call 1 participant" and it won't call that person.

If I open a chat and send a chat message, I get the little (!) icon indicating that it wasn't sent. Then if I restart Skype the message won't be saved anywhere. If I copy the message, I can't paste after closing down Skype. Instead I need paste it somewhere to retrieve it later.

It seems like this issue is more likely to happen if I start Skype on a computer that hasn't received messages in a while, and during the message syncing it can lock, but it's certainly not the only time.

Is this a known issue with a workaround or is there some way for me to automatically get notified that Skype is exhibiting this behavior so I can restart it?

Both Maverick and Natty has exhibited this behavior and has been happening to me for months, I thought it was just something related to my netbooks but since the desktop computer I have also experiences this it seems like a general issue.

Comment: Arrr! I thought these were all different bugs with Skype. I've adopted the habit of just rebooting before I make a Skype call. There is a script here somewhere to only start one instance of Skype at a time, maybe that can be combined with another to just restart Skype every hour or so? This is past my skill level but I'd love to see this fixed soon.

Comment: I also have many problems with Skype...

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).